# Symfony2 / Doctrine - Joining Mysql and Sqlite Entities

Tags: orm, join, symfony, doctrine-orm, relationships

I'm having a problem with Symfony2 / Doctrine.

I'm starting to think that I'm trying to do the impossible, joining 2 seperate databases together via a relationship.

- I've got a mysql database, and an sqlite database.
- I've got 2 bundles (each talking to one of the databases each)
- I've got 2x Entity Managers, with mappings working correctly.

I can access each database, via it's own Entity Manager just fine, Each bundle can access the other bundles Entity Manager, and it's all working well on that front.

The Sqlite database is locked-down to another application, and I have to use it as-is.  The mysql-database is mine to do whatever I need with.

- In the sqlite database I've got a "Projects" table
- In the mysql database I've got a "Tasks" table.
- One project can have many tasks.

My tasks table has a project_id field, which is populated with the ID from the projects table.  What I'm trying to do is to make this relationship work properly, so that I can use twig to do what you normally can do with twig in more normal situations.  I.e. call something like **{{ project.tasks }}**  or **{{ tasks.projects }}**.

At the moment I've got some code in the Project controller, passing the Tasks to the views and vice versa.  This does work, but it's quite cumbersome.  What I'd really like to do is to have the ORM mapping working correctly between each entity.

**Can Doctrine/Symfony2 do this, or am I trying to do the impossible?**

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's an extract from my config.yml file.

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager:   agile
        entity_managers:
            glue:
                connection:       glue
                mappings:
                    WebplaceGlueBundle: ~
            agile:
                connection:       agile
                mappings:
                    WebplaceAgileBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar problem at OpenSky: we have some data stored in MongoDB, and some stored in MySQL. We use an extension to stof's DoctrineExtensions bundle:

https://github.com/opensky/DoctrineExtensionsBundle/tree/orm2odm_references_current

This lets us add `@Gedmo\ReferenceOne` annotations between ODM and ORM. You might be able to use this directly between two ORM connections, but if not it'll give you a starting point for handling relationships between different persistence layers...

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\ReferenceOne(
 *     type="document",
 *     class="MyBundle\Document\User",
 *     identifier="userId"
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, 
Thanks for the reply mate,

I've tried directly mapping the entities between each other using the longer Company\SomethingBundle\Entity\SomeEntity notation in each of the model orm files, but it looks like each of the Entities still looks in it's own database nomatter what, even if the entity is in a seperate db.  I then get a bunch of error messages about mapped superclasses...  

Might have to resign to the old controller hack to get it working.. sigh..

Comment: Hi egruz, any news about this problem?